# Clip pixels inside area with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, clipping

I have a rectangle that i need to clip (i mean clip pixels inside my area, not outside).  glScissor works almost like i want, but as i said, i need to clip pixels INSIDE my area, but scissor works vice versa.  Does glScissor can make thing that i need, or GL has other methods?

Here example what i need to do (I drew picture for example):

[image: drawing]

Comment: The efficient way would be via [`GL_NV_scissor_exclusive`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_scissor_exclusive.txt), but this one is nvidia-specific and not very widely supported in general, but [`GL_EXT_window_rectangles`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_window_rectangles.txt) also offers such a functionality, and is more widely available.